# error when trying to click on element that was hidden and then made visible again

Tags: javascript

When I click a button I am using axios to send some data to my node.js backend and when the button is clicked I hide it and show a spinner. If something goes wrong, I hide the spinner and show the buttons again. That works fine. But if I click on the button after it is visible again I get an error that says :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
>       at renderLoader (26786sdg72635287hd)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.document.querySelector.addEventListener.e

HTML:

```
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    const renderLoader = parent => {
        const loader = `
           <div class="loader">
                <svg>
                    <use href="/images/icons.svg#icon-cw"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        `;
        parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', loader);
    };

    const clearLoader = () => {
        const loader = document.querySelector('.spinner');
        if (loader) {
            loader.parentElement.removeChild(loader);
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('.approve').addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const csrf = document.querySelector('[name=_csrf]').value;
        const productId = document.querySelector('[name=productId]').value;
        document.querySelector('.approve').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.querySelector('.reject').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        renderLoader(document.querySelector('.spinner'));


        axios.post('/account/approve/' + productId, {
            status: 'approved'
        },
            {
                headers: {
                    'csrf-token': csrf
                }

            })
            .then(response => {

                const approveBox = document.querySelector('.dashboard-list-box');
                const successMessage = document.querySelector('.success');
                approveBox.classList.add('fade-out');
                successMessage.classList.add('notification');
                successMessage.innerHTML = response.data.message;
                clearLoader();

            })
            .catch(err => {
                clearLoader();
                document.querySelector('.approve').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.querySelector('.reject').style.visibility = 'visible';
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an error, `clearLoader` is called which removes the `.spinner` element and I think it shouldn't, to fix this just change this line:

```
const loader = document.querySelector('.spinner');
```

to

```
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');
```

from inside the `clearLoader` function. That seems to have been your intention given the variable's name.

Comment: Ah, yes. This is it!

Answer (score 0):

first click you are remove element in dom '.spinner' and After second click your are calling this renderLoader function and you are sending html element as prop so you cant do this because you are remove with this function '.spinner' html element so you need hide element or you need create this element again.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but if I click on the button again then it starts the whole process again ie: creates the div with the loader again `renderLoader(document.querySelector('.spinner'));` Well, it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of hiding the specific element like `document.querySelector('.approve').style.visibility = 'hidden'` that you have, you should look into something like `document.querySelector('.approve').classList.add('hide);`

also in terms of why insertAdjacentHTML is not working, post it outside of the scope of the const 'renderLoader'.

Also, creating one object that accounts for `document.querySelector('.approve')` and `document.querySelector('.reject')`